# I'd like to replace my self-created role code with Rolify but am unsure of how to deal with deleting/undoing existing migrations, etc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, rolify

The title pretty much says it all, but I'll try to go into a bit more detai. I basically created my own role-based permission system before learning that role-based permissions are a "solved problem" and that Rolify is a better solution than what I've created. I'd like to replace my code with the Rolify code but keep running into errors that require me to run

```
rake db:migrate
```

which then simply informs me that a Role table already existing within the database, etc. **My inclination is simply to create a migration that removes the roles table, but is this the right thing to do?**

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to first use the following to make sure actually dropping your roles table is the proper solution.

`rake db:migrate:down VERSION=MigrationTimestamp`

You can always run the same command with 'up' instead of 'down' to re-create the table. Of course, if you drop the table, then you will lose all of the records in it. Make sure to back up your data if you need it.

My personal opinion on this would be to actually just delete the initial migration that creates the roles table along with any migrations that update that table, if removing the roles table is the right solution. Then, create a rake task to use just for the next release to drop the roles table. That way, if someone else needs to work on your codebase in the future, they will not have a migration that creates a table and a migration that deletes the same table when they get up and running. The history of what happened in you migrations is not really necessary for future work, as long as you document that the upgrade to an authorization gem was done and the result was that you no longer needed the roles table.

While on the subject...I use the Declarative Authorization gem and find it much more effective than Rolify. I have a separate roles table that stays intact and works well with the D.A. gem. It is definitely worth checking out.